# String array with key and value Remove already exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I found some similar questions, but none helped me.

I have an array, and I am pushing items into it. I want to check if there is already an item then removes and add a new value.

I am doing this in the success of an ajax call,

```
var taxSplitUp = []; // my array

// ajax call here, in the success 

for (var i in data.d) { 

  var ItemTaxAmt= data.d[i].ItemTaxAmt;
  var TaxName = data.d[i].TaxName;

  var idx = $.inArray(TaxName, taxSplitUp); // checks if already exist

  if (idx == -1) {

    var tx1 = '{"' + TaxName + '":"' + parseFloat(ItemTaxAmt).toFixed(2) + '"}';
    taxSplitUp.push(tx1);
  } 

  else {
    taxSplitUp.splice(idx, 1); // removing
    var t1 = taxSplitUp[TaxName]; // selecting the value from array

    var tx1 = '{"' + TaxName + '":"' + parseFloat(ItemTaxAmt).toFixed(2) + parseFloat(t1).toFixed(2) + '"}';

    taxSplitUp.push(tx1);
  }

}
```

Here if the same key came, then I want to add the values together and want only one in the array, but the checking always returns false and adds another into the array.

please help.

Comment: You want to remove duplicate value or remove all values from array and then insert new values?

Comment: I want to remove the duplicate one and insert with the updated tax amount

Comment: Why don't you just use indexOf which is par t of the JavaScript Array object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.inArray wont work with associative array. Try below solution

```
for (var i in data) {

  var ItemTaxAmt= data[i].ItemTaxAmt;
  var TaxName = data[i].TaxName;

  console.log(TaxName);

  $.map(taxSplitUp, function(item, index) {
 if (item.TaxName == TaxName) {
   item.ItemTaxAmt = ItemTaxAmt;

 }else{

    taxSplitUp.push({
        'TaxName' :TaxName,
        'ItemTaxAmt' : ItemTaxAmt
    });
 }
});

}
console.log(taxSplitUp);
```